# How to update sprite position faster?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For the game I'm trying to do, I have quite a few objects:

[image]

Where all start with a specific sprite, like the Hero:

[image]

Except that the Hero is the only one which has an `Animator` component and follows animation states.

The other game objects would get their sprite and position based on the Hero, using the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpritePosition : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private string objectName;
  [SerializeField] private int objectIndex;
  [SerializeField] private int objectR;
  [SerializeField] private int objectG;
  [SerializeField] private int objectB;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private SpriteRenderer objectRenderer;
  private GameObject hero;
  private Rigidbody2D heroRigidBody;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  private Sprite currentHeroSprite;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private Sprite[] spriteGroup;

  private void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroRigidBody = hero.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    heroRenderer = hero.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    currentHeroSprite = heroRenderer.sprite;

    heroResourcesScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroResources>();
    Debug.Log(objectName + "(" + objectR + ", " + objectG + ", " + objectB + ")");
    spriteGroup = heroResourcesScript.spriteGroup[objectName];
  }

  private void Update() {
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();

    if (currentHeroSprite != heroRenderer.sprite) {
      currentHeroSprite = heroRenderer.sprite;
    }

    SetSprite();
    SetPosition();
  }

  private bool shouldMirrorSprite(int index) { 
    return index >= 0 && index <= 34 ||
            index >= 69 && index <= 71 ||
            index >= 81 && index <= 83 ||
            index >= 97 && index <= 99 ||
            index >= 117 && index <= 118 ||
            index >= 133 && index <= 175;
  }
  private void SetSprite() {
    int currentSpriteIndex = int.Parse(currentHeroSprite.name.Replace("hero-body_", ""));
    objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentSpriteIndex];

    objectRenderer.color = new Color32((byte)objectR, (byte)objectG, (byte)objectB, 255);

    if (heroMovementScript.isFacingLeft && shouldMirrorSprite(currentSpriteIndex)) {
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    } else {
      transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
  }

  // for this to work, the game object must have a
  // RigidBody2D component with Freeze Position active
  // for X and Y axis
  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
}
```

Which, when added as a component, expects a name, index, and R, G, and B values:

[image]

Here, the `Name` is necessary to load specific sprites for each game object, in this script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroResources : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Dictionary<string, Sprite[]> spriteGroup = new Dictionary<string, Sprite[]>();
  void Awake () {
    spriteGroup.Add("pants", Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/pants"));
    spriteGroup.Add("boots", Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/boots"));
    spriteGroup.Add("shirt", Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/shirt"));
    spriteGroup.Add("tunic", Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/tunic"));
    spriteGroup.Add("belt", Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/belt"));

    Debug.Log(spriteGroup.Count);
  }
}
```

and the sprites are loaded from several folders in the `Resources` folder:

[image]

These spritesheets are all of the same size, so they can be cleanly sliced:

[image][image][image]

Thus, having the sprites like this, I can simply call the `SetSprite` function and the `SetPosition` function based on the Hero:

```
private void SetSprite() {
    int currentSpriteIndex = int.Parse(currentHeroSprite.name.Replace("hero-body_", ""));
    objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentSpriteIndex];

    objectRenderer.color = new Color32((byte)objectR, (byte)objectG, (byte)objectB, 255);

    if (heroMovementScript.isFacingLeft && shouldMirrorSprite(currentSpriteIndex)) {
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    } else {
      transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
  }
```

```
// for this to work, the game object must have a
  // RigidBody2D component with Freeze Position active
  // for X and Y axis
  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
```

This works, and the other sprites update based on the index of the Hero game object and follow it, so it looks like the user has a lot of equipment. However, sometimes the sprites either fail to keep up or the position falls behind a bit:

[image]

There also seems to be some black lines toward the top of the sprites. I assume this happens because the sprites do not load fast enough, and if so, is there a way to ensure these sprites load faster? Or does this have to do with a computer's performance?

Also, to have the sprites follow, I need to freeze X and Y position on the other game objects' RigidBody2D. The Hero has Transform, Sprite Renderer, Box Collider 2D, RigidBody2D, two scripts (HeroMovement and HeroResources), and Animator components, while the other game objects only have Transform, Sprite Renderer, RigidBody2D, and a script (SpritePosition)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of positioning the clothes yourself you could let Transform component do the heavy lifting by just placing the cloth GameObjects under the hero GameObject with correct offsets.

This way you could also have HeroAnimator component that gets all the clothing components under the hero with GetComponentsInChildren at startup and changes the sprites and flip them to match movement direction. Clothing components could focus

> because the sprites do not load fast enough

You're loading all the sprite resources with HeroResources.Awake so they should all be loaded to memory during startup. Same goes for all sprites you're referencing in your scene.

String operations like this in **update method** can generate surprising amount of garbage for the garbage collector which can affect performance down the line.

```
int currentSpriteIndex = int.Parse(currentHeroSprite.name.Replace("hero-body_", ""));
```

Its good to note that implementing something like this can get really tricky. Many 2D games that let you change outfit use [skeletal animation](https://unity.com/features/2danimation) or have very limited set of minimal animations.

Comment: I changed the line to this `int.Parse(currentSpriteName.Substring(currentSpriteName.LastIndexOf("_") + 1));` to execute inside the Hero script so that should reduce some of the garbage. I tried putting the other game objects as children of the Hero but that removes the scale ability. Also, when the Hero moves/jumps it changes velocity (x or y). Should I be modifying the other game object's velocities along with the position? I noticed `body.velocity = heroRigidBody.velocity;` doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you parent the cloth objects inside the hero you should not need to move them at all, unless they're of different size during animation in which case you'll need to configure pivot (center point) of each cloth animation sprite. Only case where you might need to offset them would be in cases where hero crouches or something. Only hero should have rigidbody in this case, can't think of any valid reasons for clothing objects to have ridigbody. Scaling should be ok provided hero has uniform scale as non-uniform scale can produce plethora of issues.

Comment: Good flexible hierarchy for something like this is to have parent Player/Actor GameObject which has Movement script and rigidbody. Then as children you could have 3 GameObjects one for character/hero sprite, one for collider and one for clothing which has all clothing GameObjects as children.

Comment: Do you think it'd be that much more demanding on memory if I were to create a base spritesheet based only on the head and hands, and a separate spritesheet for the legs and arms, so that when loaded there is no risk of overlap?

Comment: I'd avoid premature optimisation and use [the build in profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to troubleshoot any performance issues. Do what you find the most efficient in terms of workflow and workload as having to draw new sprite for each clothing piece for each animation frame is quite tasking as it is.  Many games just swap out the whole character spritesheet which removes the ability to change individual clothing pieces but is a lot less work.

Comment: Yeah, it would be less work, but I'd love to do a game like Castlevania Symphony Of The Night but with Zero's movement from Megaman X4, while being able to fully customize all equipment

Comment: By the way, is it that much more demanding to try to use some form of sprite merger and apply animations to it?

Comment: You can make things a bit easier by making sure all animation frames for player and all clothing are of the same size (Bigger sprite sheets with a lot wasted space). This way you you can just play the clothing animations on top of player animations with a lot less positioning issues.  Skeletal animations are more technical but often allow you to just swap your characters head, torso, hands or legs with another sprite quite easily. If you're good at frame by frame animations it can be difficult to make them look as good though.

Comment: Yeah, all my sprites are 256x256. But would this work if the player swaps out equipment? For example, the pants sprites are `hero-pants-1_xx` because when the player equips a different set of pants (or armor) these would be `hero-pants-2_xx` which I would load by expanding on the use of `objectIndex`. If it’s not possible to know which pants will be equipped in scene mode, is it possible to programmatically change them in game mode?

Comment: If your sprite sheets are in identical order and in identical places like in form of a grid for example. All you really need to do is set swap the sprite sheet hero-pants-1 to hero-pants-2 and either reset the animation to 0 or just use the current animation frame index/key.

Comment: do you know how I should swap spritesheets? I've been looking at this tutorial, https://www.erikmoberg.net/article/unity3d-replace-sprite-programmatically-in-animation , but since I am not loading any sprites, just using the ones with which animations are made, how can I tell Unity which spritesheet to use?

Comment: Check out [SpirteAtlas](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.html) its resource like any other you can load with Resource.Load then use it to get sprites from specific atlas / spritesheet.